# require_once including old file, latest file values not considered

Tags: php

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    require_once('dbConnect.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from TableName;");
    echo mysql_result($result, 0);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

In the above code sample, I can see that require_once is using older values of the file "dbConnect.php". The login credentials present in dbConnect.php is of older values, and not the latest one I updated recently. I can see this in the error message.
Please suggest how to overcome this error.

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Is this the complete code?

Comment: When you made the new version of `dbConnect.php` did you put it in a different directory OR do you have more than one of these in different directories. _I am guessing that the answer to one of these must be YES_

Comment: what is your web server? apache, nginx? 
did you try  restart web server?

Comment: @RiggsFolly dbConnect.php is in the same directory as GetData.php

Comment: Is the code you show called `GetData.php`?

Comment: Are you using any cacheing on the server that might be holding the old file contents?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, the code snippet pasted above is GetData.php

Comment: Are you using session for storing database users, password, db name etc?

Comment: No, I'm not using session

Comment: If you can, then try a simple test: put die('hello webgenius'); into dbConnect.php with new values, refresh the page and see if it fails with that message or not.